# Windows Message for all resizing actions

Tags: winapi, resize, message, wndproc

Does someone know a message that gets send at the end of a resizing event (like double clicking app bar, maximize button click, drag to the top of the screen, ...), a good example is WM_EXITSIZEMOVE, but it's only at the end of the dragging of the window size bar.

So my question is, does it exist a message that gets called when any sizing event has occured, at the end of it (not like WM_SIZE)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll get a `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` message with the `SWP_NOSIZE` flag cleared at the end of any sizing event. There's no other message that indicates sizing has finished other than `WM_EXITSIZEMOVE` which indicates the end of a modal moving/sizing loop. If you get `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` without previously getting `WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE` then you can assume you're not being resized modally.

Comment: A hint to anyone using this technique to detect *client* size changes in addition to *window* size changes: Also listen to `SWP_FRAMECHANGED` to account for situations like adding/removing a menu, adding/removing scroll bars, or changing the border from overlapped -> popup and vice versa.